# How do I find $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ when $\lim_{x \to a} [3f(x)+g(x)]=1$ and$\lim_{x \to a} [2f(x)-3g(x)]=8$?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I had to solve the next exercise:

> If $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are functions that satisfy $$\lim_{x \to a} [3f(x)+g(x)]=1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{x \to a} [2f(x)-3g(x)]=8,$$ then find the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$

---

This is what I did:

Let $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=\ell$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=t$. Using laws of limits I wrote $3\ell+t=1$ and $2\ell-3t=8$. Then $t=1-3\ell \implies 2\ell-3(1-3\ell)=8$ After some algebraic manipulations I got that $\ell=1$. Then $3(1)+t=1 \implies t=-2$. Finally, since $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)\neq 0$, then $$\lim_{x \to a}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})=  \frac{\lim_{x \to a}{f(x)}}{\lim_{x \to a}{g(x)}}=\frac{1}{-2}=\frac{-1}{2}.$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

You are starting with that assumption that $f$ and $g$ have limits at $a$ which is not legitimate.

Multiply the first equation by $2$ , the second on by $3$  and subtract one from the other. You will see that $g$ has  a limit as $x \to a$. Now use the first equation to show that $f$ has  a limit as $x \to a$. Now you can proceed the way you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to see that :

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{3 \left(3f(x)+g(x)\right) + (2f(x)-3g(x))}{2\left(3f(x)+g(x)\right) - 3\left(2f(x)-3g(x)\right)}$$

Therefore the limit when $x$ tends to $a$ is equal to
$$\frac{3 \times 1 + 8}{2 \times 1 - 3 \times 8} = - \frac{1}{2}$$